# How can I get a specific string?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, telegram-bot

```
def get_system_info():
      command = "free -h"
      return subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True).strip()
@bot.message_handler(commands=['si'])
def send_echo(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, get_system_info())
```

Result:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            62G         49G        5.3G         69M        7.5G         12G
Swap:          1.0G        5.8M        1.0G
```

The result I need:

```
Memory,
total: 62G
used: 49G
free: 5.3G
shared: 69M
buff/cache: 7.5G
available: 12G
```

I tried to do it via splitlines, but it didn't work out

Comment: `it didn't work out`: Please post what you have tried and what went wrong so that we can help you.

Comment: Tried to do 

return subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True).strip().splitlines(1)

Result:

total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available


I tried to replace .splitlines(1) with other numbers, but this line was always output

Comment: Please edit your question and paste your code, properly formatted.

Answer (score 0):

You can proceed like this:

```
# decode used to convert bytes into string, then split it around whitespaces/newlines
output = get_system_info().decode('utf-8').split()
d = {}
for i in range(0, 6):
    d[text[i]] = text[i + 7]
```

Through this, you can capture key-value pairs from `total` to `available`. Values for my machine :

```
>>> d
{'total': '15G', 'used': '6.9G', 'free': '486M', 'shared': '842M', 'buff/cache': '8.2G', 'available': '7.6G'}
```

I believe you can print this dictionary in whatever format you require from here on-wards.